# What is mean ETA in web hosting industry?

Tags: linux, web-server, hosting

All of our servers down. Our web hosting provider says "We do not have an ETA of when this problem will be resolved." What is mean ETA?

Comment: Originally a shipping term, meaning "Estimated Time of Arrival". In this case, it means "we don't have an estimate of the time when this problem will be resolved".

Answer (score 2):

ETA = Estimated Time of Arrival

When the hosting provider says that, it means they don't know when the problem will be resolved yet.